# Format a list into a string Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, interleave

I have this code that interleaves two words and outputs the new interleaved word as a tuple, but I need it too be a raw string.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def interleave(word1,word2):
    return ''.join(list(map(str, zip_longest(word1,word2,fillvalue=''))))
```

If inputting the words, cat and hat, this outputs

```
('h', 'c')('a', 'a')('t', 't').
```

But I need it to output

```
hcaatt
```

How could I go about formatting this list into a normal string

Comment: see [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

With `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` and `zip()` functions:

```
import itertools

w1, w2 = 'cat', 'hat'
result = ''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(w2, w1)))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
hcaatt
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use reduce to reach your goal:

```
word1, word2 = 'cat', 'hat'
result = ''.join(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, zip(word1, word2)))
print(result)
```